# How do you truncate stack trace output in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, stack-overflow

I'm trying to debug a StackOverflowError in a Kotlin program.

Annoyingly, the entire 2600-line stack trace is shown in the console output in IntelliJ IDEA.

Is there any setting to truncate or hide this stack trace so I don't have to scroll up 2,600 lines to see where the error occurred and logs from before the error? I'm used to other programming languages which typically truncate long stack traces.

Comment: Did you try Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Console | Fold console lines that contain?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I suppose that would work for a specific function :-\